# How to enable the turbo button on acer predator helios 300 in Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, laptop, acer

I've just bought one of the eight different models of the [Acer Predator Helios 300](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/predator-models/laptops/predatorhelios300).

It has a turbo button which supposed to overclock CPUs upon being pressed.

Apparently without additional configuration it doesn't work in Ubuntu.

The laptop had windows initially, which I've replaced with Ubuntu 18.04.

How do I enable that hardware feature?

Comment: What was the result when you went to https://us.answers.acer.com/app/chat/chat_landing/nosearch/1 and asked the Acer TS rep?

Answer (score 1):

I've just sent a patch to Linux kernel for supporting Turbo mode,
but this takes some time to get merged, So I've created a temporary repository for this on my Github.

https://github.com/JafarAkhondali/acer-predator-turbo-and-rgb-keyboard-linux-module

simply run `sudo ./install.sh` and hope that turbo button could work fine.

If you are using 4-zone RGB model, then the repo supports dynamic coloring effect as well (more info is available in readme).

If the features worked for you, kindly make an issue on repo so I can add more info on readme.

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking for a solution to this. What I do is the following: if you have dual-booting with Windows/Ubuntu, you can press the turbo button in Windows, restart your laptop, and then you'll have the fan in turbo mode when you initiate Ubuntu. That's a workaround though.

Comment: The OP says "The laptop had windows initially, which I've replaced with Ubuntu 18.04." So this solution isn't going to help. But as this will probably help future users who are dual booting, your answer may not be deleted. Next time only answer with what the OP wants.